# Change Icon color when clicked

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I would like to know how to do to change the color of the icon when clicked. I researched but no results, can anyone fix me? thx  `<ion-icon name="icon-calendar-check-o" class="calendar"></ion-icon>`

Answer (score -1):

Use this Jquery code

```
  var clicked=false;

 $("#MyIcon").click(function(){
        if(clicked){
            $(this).css('color', 'red');
            clicked  = false;
        } else {
            $(this).css('color', 'blue');
            clicked  = true;
        }   
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I did not understand how I should use it. Could you explain me?

Comment: The question is related to Ionic/Angular, not jQuery